# Fast changing QLineEdit crashing the application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, qt

I have three QLineEdit fields, whose content is changing really fast (100/second).
Somehow it crashes the application. Maybe it's a bug or I make a mistake.

Here is some code:

```
acc[0]->setText(QString("%1").arg(acceleration.x));
acc[1]->setText(QString("%1").arg(acceleration.y));
acc[2]->setText(QString("%1").arg(acceleration.z));
```

The call stack: http://pastebin.com/RmkZHTjk

And sometimes I get this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x6518cbb3
>   (QtGuid4.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location
>   0x0000002c.

Call stack for this: http://pastebin.com/c1u53a0Z

I tried it with QLabel, then I get another error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x751a9617 in
>   Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception:
>   std::bad_alloc at memory location
>   0x03aeea70..

Call stack: http://pastebin.com/G4yeiW2Y

Comment: @Roland Soós: Did you tried to do some changes with the code? For example, `setText()` just with one `QLineEdit`, or instead of `QLineEdit` use `QLabel`? Interesting, what will be the result... Is it really so needed to print acceleration values with this speed?

Comment: Did you try with the strings from the backtrace at a slower speed (or just a single lineedit?)? Also, how long are the backtraces? Sometimes stack overflows cause crashes deep in Qt and one scratches his head until he notices the size of the stack.

Comment: Yes, I tried it with QLabel, then I get some another error. I've added this info to the question. I tried to limit it to 10change/sec. It worked well on 6% processor usage. On 100change/sec the processor usage is 50%(I have 2 core).

Comment: @Frank: I don't think that it's stackoverflow, because I don't have recursion.

Comment: Wow. bad alloc when resizing a vector in the backend store?
Hmm. Maybe you run your code in a loop without returning to the event loop? Then the UI has no chance to actually update itself and changes (dirty widgets list) might pile up. Maybe try with a QTimer.

Comment: @Frank: I get data from my accelerometer device on another thread and when the received data parsed it cals the afterparse function, which actually updates the values on the form. I'm new in QT, just started yesterday.

Comment: Now I get the label issue again, on 10fps :S

Comment: @Roland Soós: How do you get the received data from the other thread to the UI thread? I think more context/code might help.

Comment: @Frank: I added the qt source codes to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574147/qt-heap-memory-corruption

Comment: @Frank: I receive data on bluetooth connection and I start a thread with Boost to care about the reading the data

Comment: @Roland Soós: It looks to me like you call setText() from the non-UI thread. That won't work, QWidgets are not thread-safe.

Comment: @Frank: Do you know any solution for QT to make it works?

Comment: If you are calling setText from other than main thread (UI-thread), you just need to move that operation to the main thread. Add a slot function to your mainwindow (where your labels are) and send a signal with acceleration values as parameters from your other thread.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. This solved every issue. Could someone write an "answer" to mark as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets get this closed. This is Frank's answer posted as comment a week ago.

@Roland Soós: It looks to me like you call setText() from the non-UI thread. That won't work, QWidgets are not thread-safe. -- Frank