# Qt heap memory corruption

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, qt

I'm writing a Qt 4.6 application (without the qt designer) and when I close the program I get this error from Visual Studio:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in
>   Test.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the
>   heap, which indicates a bug in
>   Test.exe or any of the DLLs it has
>   loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user
>   pressing F12 while Test.exe has focus.
>
> The output window may have more
>   diagnostic information.

Here is the source code:

- `Main.cpp` http://pastebin.com/DeUvZSHU
- `TesterWindow.h` http://pastebin.com/SEVr8x40
- `TesterWindow.cpp` http://pastebin.com/MYUtZZGw
- `Device.h` http://pastebin.com/bXKxVrmW
- `Device.cpp` http://pastebin.com/H1kMcRes
- `ExtWiiMote.h` http://pastebin.com/uX3HT9Yw
- `ExtWiiMote.cpp` http://pastebin.com/p2TKZdHv

(You can't compile it, I can't share the used library)

What's wrong?

Comment: why not post the code here? Otherwise use http://pastebin.com/

Comment: it's 6 file and I thought that's easier. I added the files now to pastebin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ExtWiiMote.h` you declared

```
QLabel* dots[3][3];
```

and in the `ExtWiiMote.cpp` you use `dots[3][0]...`.

Fix `dots` array size and probably you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error last month but since lots of different problems can cause it, I'm not sure my answer will help you.

This was caused by a derived class (Child) without virtual destructor. The error pops up each time the debugger was entering the destructor of Child. Since I'm at work and can not access to the website to get source code I can not check this.

Hope this may help you

Comment: I've added the files to pastebin, you can check it.
I'll try your suggestion, maybe that helps.