# QT widget alignment problem

Tags: qt, qt4

I've created a form with code and I have a big problem. Every element aligmented to the bottom. I painted the clear and aligned space blue on the picture. How can I set every alignment to top?

If you need the code in this question you'll find it: [Qt heap memory corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574147/qt-heap-memory-corruption)

[image]

Comment: Are you using Qt Designer ? Do you have a ui file you could post ?

Comment: @Jérôme: No, I'm not. I'm writing the codes without the editor.

Comment: Could you put the code you're using to create these widgets ? Especially `Kamera Panel` and `Accellerometre Panel`, which I didn't find in the code of your other question.

Comment: @Jérôme: Thanks for helping. I've found out what was the problem as you see in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem. I used addStretch() on every layout after initialization, so it spaced the other widgets to the bottom of the form.

I thought yesterday, that addStrech(int) sets the widht ration for every vertical layout in a horizontal layout. Now I know addStrech is for spacing.